# Creating a new column that lists multiple rows in another column together

Tags: r

I want to create a new column that lists values in multiple rows in another column together. The data looks like this at the moment:

[image: data frame]

A small example of an expected outcome would be:

```
word_no.  file        word      phones
2         021A_...6   STRANGE   S,T,R,EY,N,JH
3         021A_...6   ISN'T     AH,Z,AH,N,T
4         021A_...6   IT        AH,T
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a new column that list all the phones within a word in one raw, so that I can analyse which words are bisyllabic later.  For instance, the phones "S", "T", "R", "EY", "N", and "JH" should be listed all together in the 2nd row in a new column, next to the phone column.

```
>install.packages("dplyr")
>library(dplyr)
>pbisyldat $phones <- rep(NA, nrow(pbisyldat))
> pbisyldat $phones[pbisyldat %>% group_by(word_no., file, word) %>% 
  +     summarise(phones = toString(phone))]
```

I tried the code above, but it yields an error.

```
Error in toString(phone) : object 'phone' not found
```

This also yields an error.

```
> pbisyldat$phones[pbisyldat %>% 
+                      +group_by(word_no., file) %>% 
+                      +summarise(phone = paste(phone, collapse = ", "))]
```

```
Error in group_by(word_no., file) : object 'word_no.' not found
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome at SO! Could you please add a minimal data set as code here instead of linking a picture so that it is easier for us to provide a solution? THX! PS: The easiest way to create R code from your data variable is `dput(my_data_variable)` and add the code to your question (formatted as code).

Comment: its `phones` not `phone`

Comment: Could you please add an result example (how the result data shall look alike). E. G. it is unclear how want to concatenate the phones into one column (which delimiter)

Comment: @R Yoda I added an example of the expected outcome in the post! Hope it helps.

Comment: @Sotos I tried with "phones", but still give the same error :(

Comment: Hello @aoooooiiiiiiiiiiiiiii. It would be more helpful to include the dataset as text rather than a picture (but well done for including ALT text). This is because some people won't be able to view the image and some people who might try to replicate the problem will not want to retype the content (and even if they do they may make errors).

Answer (score 0):

As others already noted, a minimal dataset and a how the result looks like helps a lot.

From what I understood, the code below might give you some idea to move forward:

```
library(data.table)    
w_n <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3)
phone <- c("s", "t", "r","ah", "z", "ah")
dt <- data.table(w_n, phone)

output <- dt[, paste0(phone |> unique(), collapse = "-")
             , .(w_n)]
```

Else, if you want to append the result within your dataset, you might try:

```
dt[, output := paste0(phone |> unique(), collapse = "-")
             , .(w_n)]
```